# PermissionError: [Errno 1]: Openpyxl not letting me open Excel files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

it's been a few years since I've done anything with Python and I never remember having issues with openpyxl. All I am trying to do is simply open up an excel file using openpyxl. All of the sudden I can't perform this simple task. I'm using IDLE. Thought this was exclusive to excel, but I also can't open OpenOffice files which I was able to do previously. Here's what my code looks like:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('fileName.xlsx')
```

And here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('fileName.xlsx')
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 310, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 126, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 98, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1250, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'fileName.xlsx'
```

What I've done so far to try to solve the issue, which hasn't worked:

1. Made sure the excel file is closed before entering the code
2. Made sure the program is in the correct directory
3. Given full disk access to Finder, Terminal, IDLE, Python Launcher, and Excel

On macOS Monterey. From reading previous questions on this it looks like this became an issue with newer versions of MacOS. Yet none of the solutions offered work for me. Granted, last time I tried to code with this module was 2020. So is there something else I need to try, or is there another module where I can open up excel spreadsheets? Because literally all I need to do is have the program open up a spreadsheet and generate a list of items from the cells. Not really rocket science here. Any help is appreciated, and let me know if additional info is needed.

Comment: I believe filename is a keyword argument, not a positional argument.  `load_workbook(filename='fileName.xlsx')`

Comment: Yeah the command syntax is OK. Looks like maybe your openpyxl version is a little out of date, not that I expect it to be the issue but doesn't harm to update if so. I've heard this error can be an issue due to the MACOS protection (quarantining the app), however other than a suggestion of using sudo to run the command I dont know of any [absolute] fixes. I dont use MACOS myself

Comment: Wanna give an update for anyone who happens to see this. The problem was with IDLE, not my computer. I opened up an interactive session in terminal and the code works completely fine (full disk access still granted to Terminal).